# How to find all images in folder

Tags: finder

I'd like to list all images in a folder (and subfolders), but I get no results in Finder for any search unless I search 'This Mac'.

I select the folder I wish to search, select 'images' as the 'kind' in the search box, top right, but although it says 'Searching "foldername"' nothing ever gets returned, unless I select 'This Mac',  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you say works for me.  Perhaps mention what OS you are using?  Do searches work with other selections or 'kind'?  What kinds of images are in that folder that should be found?

Comment: What kind of images *format* (jpg, png, tiff, cr2, raw, …) are you looking for?

Comment: Yosemite, 'kind' doesn't seem to work with anything other than This Mac

Comment: I'd like to find all images in a folder and sub folders

Comment: Just tried it here.  Works flawlessly on Yosemite.  Here's what I did (so that you can compare): Navigated to Pictures, typed in "a" into the search box to initiate the search, added a criteria (auto-set to "Kind" is "Any"), removed the "a" by hitting backspace to not limit the search to files containing "a", chose "Image" from the drop-down showing "Any".  Voilá!  Shows all supported image types. in the subfolders of Pictures.

Comment: I followed your description exactly, nothing is displayed. Should I have to wait? Maybe they are getting indexed, or something?

Comment: Have you possibly selected Search This Mac = in Finder Preferences, Advanced -  when what you really want is Search Current Folder?

Comment: No, it's set to 'Search The Current Folder', I think you're on the right track though, I'm new to Macs ('really'!) and have probably got a setting wrong, somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get frustrated using the Finder application to find anything. I guess I don't have a mind that works like the authors of the Finder application. If you are used to using commands you can try the following.

1. Open a Terminal application window.
2. Use the `cd` command to change to the base folder where the files
   are. The command `pwd` will give your current folder.
3. Enter to the command

   ```
   find . -name "filesToFind" -print
   ```

   and the current base folder and all subfolders will be searched.

For example to find all files ending the `.txt` on your desktop, open a Terminal window and type:

```
cd desktop
find . -name "*.txt" -print
```

Note: The instructions for the `find` command can be found by typing the command `man find` or at [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

To find (jpg,png,svg) you can type:

```
find . -name "*.**g" -print
```